# Figure sequence 2

Tags: logical-deduction, sequence

Can somebody explain why C is the correct answer?

[image]

Comment: Where did you get this from? If it's from another site, please state the source :)

Comment: I would like more info on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the process of elimination, we can immediately cross out

> D 
>  As this has already appeared before and the sequence doesn't seem to be repeating

and

> A 
>  As this just doesn't fit with the sequence 
>  So far, the pictures in the question that has only half the circle filled with black facing right and left only. Thus, having one that faces down would be wrong

Then,

> B can also be eliminated 
>  This is quite similar to sequence #3 in the question but the only directions that I have seen are only horizontal and vertical ones. Option B is a diagonal one so we can cross this out

**CONCLUSION**

This leaves only one option left, which is

> C

Answer (score 1):

> The rings all consist of 4 quarters that are coloured black or white. However, these quarters alternate between having been split along diagonal lines or along horizontal vertical lines. Even though you cannot see which way the first ring is split, it must have been along diagonals to allow for an alternating pattern. Only answer C allows that pattern to continue.